# Protecting a row in which column F is a to timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

How to lock or protect a row after data entry or input in Google sheet. Column F is a "Timestamp" and it is a blank all time. I need to protect the Row when F not a blank

There is an error in the second line:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

```
function onEdit() {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() != 'TheNameOfTheSheetYouWantThisToWorkIn') return;//change to whatever sheet your using
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && !e.range.isBlank()) {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).protect();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `How to lock or protect a row after data entry or input in Google sheet. Column F is a "Timestamp" and it is a blank all time.`, I guess that you want to run the script when a value is inputted to a cell of the column "F".
- You want to protect the row which has the edited cell in the column "F".

#### Modification points:

- About the error of `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`, in this case, your script doesn't declare `e`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- In this case, in order to run the script as the owner, please use the installable OnEdit trigger. For this, it is required to rename the function name from `onEdit` to others. Because, when the function `onEdit` is installed as the installable OnEdit trigger, when the cell is edited, the script is run 2 times.

When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and [please install the OnEdit trigger as the installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). When you want to run this script, please edit the cell of column "F" of the sheet `TheNameOfTheSheetYouWantThisToWorkIn`. By this, the OnEdit trigger is run and the script is also run.

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() != 'TheNameOfTheSheetYouWantThisToWorkIn') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && !e.range.isBlank()) {
    var protect = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).protect();
    protect.addEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser()).removeEditors(protect.getEditors());
    if (protect.canDomainEdit()) {
      protect.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- **If you directly run the function of `installedOnEdit` at the script editor, an error like `Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` occurs. So, please be careful this. When you use this script, please edit the cell of column "F" of the sheet `TheNameOfTheSheetYouWantThisToWorkIn`.**
- When the row is protected, only owner can edit the row. Other users cannot edit the row.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question! At the moment, I can not correctly set the onEdit trigger, I will be grateful if you can help with this issue. I'm new to this, thanks in advance!

I went to the link of the trigger being installed, but I didn't know where and how to write it.

Comment: @Emil Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `At the moment, I can not correctly set the onEdit trigger` and `but I didn't know where and how to write it.`, I cannot understand about your current issue. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you, after your comment I thought about it and did everything right. The mistake was in me.
I have one more question, in this script, when editing column "F", a row is blocked, but what will the script look like if the condition is changed to column "A" and the entire row is blocked? Thanks again!

Comment: that is, I want to change column "F" to column "A"